# WSO2 APIGW - Unable to sendViaPost - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have a problem when invoking OPA (OpenPolicyAgent) from WSO2 API-GW.
The detail is:

```
TID: [101] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-322] [] [2023-06-26 06:20:33,405] []  INFO [org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender] - Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://<opa-enpoint>:443/v1/data/<tenant>/portal_api/allow] || java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1454)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1065)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:712)
```

We try to set these property into deployment.toml file:

```
[passthru_http]
'http.socket.timeout' = 3000

[synapse_properties]
'synapse.global_timeout_interval' = 3000
```

but don't resolve the problem and occurs randomly.

Have you any other solution or this ever happened?
Version of WSO2 APIGW is 3.2.0.

Thanks

[passthru_http]
'http.socket.timeout' = 3000

[synapse_properties]
'synapse.global_timeout_interval' = 3000